# How to pass a task from master to slave in master-slave pattern

Tags: java, master-slave

Ok, I've asked similar question a few days back, but it was marked as too general so I'll try one more time.

I have an assingment to create a master-slave application out of client-server. Professor specifically said that **slave should not know the task until master had sent it to him**.
My plan is to pass task object to slave, which should run it, and after finishing send results back to the master.

To this moment i tried several things:

1. I've used RMI mechanishm to *export* task object from master and *lookup* it from slave. And it is working, but as i found out when slave calls a stub method it uses master's resources. And i can't have that.
2. I've tried to send a task using JMS/ActiveMQ. The problem here is that in order to deserialize object on slave you need to have original class there. But i see it as a condition violation.

How can i transmit a task from master to slave under this condition?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With RMI, it is possible to not only do remote invocations (as the name implies) but also to pass objects by value between nodes, i.e. your task would not implement `Remote` and be passed by reference but implement `Serializable` and be passed by value. For the receiver to be able to handle what it gets, there is the [RMIClassLoader](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/rmi/server/RMIClassLoader.html).

See http://code.nomad-labs.com/2010/03/26/an-improved-rmi-tutorial-with-eclipse/ or http://www.javaworld.com/jw-12-1998/jw-12-enterprise.html?page=1 for examples.